# How to check two conditions in if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an if statement that I need to check more than one condition in.

For example:

```
if (a == 0 and b != 0 or c != 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Read about C-operators or "Operators in C" or "C language operators" or ... *sigh*

Comment: Referring "most efficient", in terms of writing do `if (!a && b || c) {...}`.

Comment: Docs are here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/3073/selection-statements#t=201609251016136318021

Comment: Hey I thought it was a pretty good question. Short, to the point, specific, not subjective, and I couldn't find anything on Stack Overflow pertaining to this. This question may help some other beginner.

Comment: Do not try to learn C by trial and error and occasional gxxgleing, this ends nowhere, but in frustration. Use a C book.

Comment: This is not really answerable. I guess by "efficient" you mean "has the fastest runtime" but that will depend on the frequency with which each condition is true (and perhaps also other parts of the program) -- optimization is a complicated process.  There is really nothing better than benchmarking  each alternative in your specific program.  And the results may change if you make any changes to your program thereafter.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `&&` (*and*) operator with the `||` (*or*) operator.

```
if (a == 0 && b != 0 || c != 0)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this on wikipedia, but it said you could use either the && or "and". I can't even find the symbol for "or". Sorry for the bad question!!!

Comment: Ugh.  It's terrible that this leaves it for readers to guess whether `(a == 0 && b != 0) || c != 0` is intended or `a == 0 && (b != 0 || c != 0)`.

Comment: @jamesdlin: `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, it "binds tighter".

Comment: @alk *I* know that, but it's not obvious to most readers, and even though *I* know what it actually does, it's not clear what was intended.  It's better to write defensive code and avoid potential ambiguity.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Well, I just directed this comment to you, as my comment was somehow referring to yours. I probably better have use something like "*Adding up to jamesdlin's comment ...*" Also I missed to upvoted your comment, which I did now.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the logical operator, for "AND" is, `&&`.

Similarly, for "OR", it is, `||`.

To evaluate some parts as a single statement, use brackets: 
In `a && (b || c)`, `a` will be evaluated first, if true then `(b || c)` will be evaluated together.

Comment: `and` is the same as `&&`  , similarly for `or` and `||`

Comment: I removed the sentence where I made the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use && operator and || operator.

&& - this is called and operator
|| - this is called or operator

```
if (a == 0 && b != 0 || c != 0)
{
    //do something
}
```